# Accessing deleted user's information

Tags: php, database, logging

I want to keep track of a user's information even after they have been deleted form the database.

There are two reasons I want to do this. Firstly, after the user is deleted, I want to display a message reading "$name has been successfully deleted". Secondly, I want to write the name of the deleted user to a log file.

What I have now does not work because when the user is deleted from the database, the name becomes NULL (I am using $_SESSION variables). Is there even a way to access this information? What's the cleverest way to do it?

Answer (score 6):

You put an extra field into the DB to signify that the record is "deleted", and do appropriate filtering wherever you attempt to use those records so that any 'deleted=true' records do not show up, e.g. at login:

```
SELECT ...
FROM users
WHERE (username = '...') AND (password = '...') AND (deleted = FALSE)
```

This way you keep the entire user record in the database, but it's not useable because it's been flagged as deleted.

Comment: You beat me to it by less than 5 seconds :(

Comment: A better way would be to have a "status" field (integer), which would allow you to have multiple statuses and save you having to create another database column. Then, you would just use: `... AND status!='0'` if "0" is deleted.

Comment: As a user I wouldn't be happy about this. If I deleted my account, I would expect it to be deleted. Might even be illegal in some jurisdictions.

Comment: And you beat me to it as well!

@Joe - it'd depend on context. Your T&C's should cover what you do with the data.

Comment: He dind't beat me, but he have hovever much more +1 than me. Strange things happen on s.o. like "reputation will attract more reputation" BTW great answer :)

Comment: @Joe Deletion of an account cannot even guarantee that all data related to you is purged. Server logs, for example, will be archived (hopefully) way longer than the age of your account - they can be used to reconstruct at least *some* information about your account. Not to mention the myriad of junk recorded by Google's (and others') cache servers.

Comment: A solution is to have a cronjob run and purge "deleted" users that are older than a week or so.

Comment: Possibly simpler alternative to soft-deletion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999407/accessing-deleted-users-information/10999658#10999658

Comment: Does anyone know why a $_SESSION variable doesn't work in this case?

Comment: @Polynomial sure it's kind of expected that logs contain data about my activities but they sure as hell shouldn't contain large amounts of PII.

Comment: @eigen93 Did you unset the session variable when deleting the user / logging them out? Did you start the session with `session_start()` in the second script?

Comment: @Polynomial Yeah, it was just a dumb mistake. Session variable works well. Thank you :-)

Comment: @eigen93 If it helped, here's my answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999407/accessing-deleted-users-information/10999658#10999658 ;)

Answer (score 2):

The cleverest answer is don't delete the user.

Have a column in the DB which marks that the user has been deleted and then treat that as if the record doesn't exist in the rest of the queries.

Comment: @Joe It's trivial to set up a daily cronjob to purge "deleted" users that are older than a week.

Comment: True. You could add that to your answer.

Comment: @joe - From a data protection standpoint, this is the right way also because you aren't destroying anything at the time of the request.  You can create a cleaner later on if you have to keep this table small

Comment: @BrianHoover Different type of data protection - Joe is referring to "amorally" storing user information, after the user has requested that you delete it.

Comment: I was talking about a quite straightforward situation where I want to end my relationship with an organisation. If I do this by requesting my account to be deleted, I expect that. If the button said 'suspend account' or 'prevent me from logging in but keep my data' that would be a different thing. I think in the UK orgs are required to keep data up-to-date on request, which is incompatible with just making it inaccessible.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the "story" of user and access it by user name or id, why don't just add a column "active" that is "False" when a user has been deleted?

Obviously when you create a user, that value will be "True" and every action related with a generic user (but if you're clever, let's say only the log in) have to take into account that column value

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But doesn't it seem simpler to have a $_SESSION variable? Why don't they work in this case?

Comment: Because `$_SESSION` is something client-side with all the "problems" that this brings to you

Answer (score 1):

The absolute best way is to never delete any data.

You simply add a bit flag to your tables labelled 'is_active' (default value of true) or 'is_deleted' (default value of false) to indicate if a piece of data is accessible.

If someone wants to delete that piece of information, you swap the flag value - you also ensure to use that flag on any queries you perform on that table to find only active pieces of data.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a way to show their name on a deletion confirmation page, you could simply pass the name as a GET parameter:

```
$name = user_get_name($user_id);
user_delete($user_id);

header('Location: deleted.php?user=' . urlencode($name));
```

Then, within your `deleted.php`, do something like this:

```
echo 'User &quot;' . htmlspecialchars($_GET['user']) . '&quot; has been deleted.';
```

FYI, the `htmlspecialchars` call is there to save you from XSS attacks.

**Update:** Make sure you're calling `session_start()` in your second script, and not unsetting session variables when deleting the user or logging them out.

Answer (score 0):

Do like:

```
$username = $user->get_name(); // OR Copy the object and use the copy for logging and messages
......

$user->delete();

$log->write_log('...... $username....');
```

PS. Have this in mind, it is illegal to store user data after deleting the profile in some countries!

Comment: Pretty sure OP is doing this in a second page, e.g. a confirmation that user "foo" has been deleted, *after* the row has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You could always write to the log file and display the message before you delete the user? That way, you've still got access to all their information when you need it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It's not ideal because if the user changes his mind against the delete, the wrong message would be sent to the log file and user

Comment: You do all three actions as part of the same routine; there's no opportunity for the user to change their mind.

Comment: And when they click Back, their account will still be deleted.

Comment: exactly, I want to allow the user to change his mind though (prevent accidental deletes and all that)

Comment: So you put in an interstitial page - "Are you sure you want to delete your account? This cannot be undone"

Answer (score 0):

OP here. I ended up using session variables (works now, was my dumb mistake). I would argue that this is the simplest way to do it, because I only wanted the deleted user's name. Also, this eliminates the dilemma of whether to keep a deleted user's information in the db